# allow access to devices not asked, in one plus 2 phone, when downloading app from google store

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have developed app in android and upload it to the google store.

It uses, the camera, location and external storage.

I have enabled this permission in the app.

Checked it in several phones and tablet including Samsung (S4, S5, Note2, Note3), Lenovo, Asus.

In One plus 2 phone when I install the app the phone doesn't request me to allow access to the devices, hence I cant get access to the camera, location and external storage and I need to allow it manually from the app info page.

I am developing in xamarin.forms for android but i guess it is general android problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides requesting permission in Marshmallow style you can set targetSdkLevel=22 (below 23 which is Marshmallow) in AndroidManifest.xml. However, you can only decrease it when not already published with 23 in store.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be ocurred because the Android version. The Marshmallow version doesn't request the permissions that app need when you download. A teammate had the same problem in a app that we developed and this problem occurred only in Marshmallows devices. His solution was verified if the required permissions were granted in the OnCreate method of the first activity of the project. If the permissions doesn't granted, the app request that.

Here is the code to request the AcessFineLocation permission:

```
string permissionLocation = Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation;
        if (Android.Support.V4.Content.ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(_context, permissionLocation) == Permission.Denied)
        {
            Android.Support.V4.App.ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions((Activity) _context, PermissionsLocation, RequestLocationId);
        }
    }
```

Probably you have to do something similar in your app.

I hope that's help you and sorry for my english write erros. I'm brazilian and my english is limited.